# Сложение нескольких элементов массива между собой

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Имеется массив `numpy`. Как можно сложить между собой все элементы массива или выборочные, например с 5 по 100 без использования циклов?

Comment: `с 5 по 100` - имеются в виду индексы или значения?

Comment: Индексы элементов массива

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [83]: import numpy as np

In [84]: a = np.random.randint(0, 10, 15)

In [85]: a
Out[85]: array([7, 8, 8, 6, 4, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 1, 4, 5])
```

суммировать элементы с индексами от 5 до 10:

```
In [86]: a[5:10]
Out[86]: array([0, 3, 0, 4, 0])

In [87]: a[5:10].sum()
Out[87]: 7
```

суммировать элементы со значениями от 5 до 7:

```
In [88]: a[(a >= 5) & (a <= 7)]
Out[88]: array([7, 6, 5])

In [89]: a[(a >= 5) & (a <= 7)].sum()
Out[89]: 18
```

PS сложить **все** элементы:

```
In [105]: a.sum()
Out[105]: 58
```